# import an xml file into a python dataframe where each tag has the same name

Tags: python, pandas, xml, dataframe

I am trying to import this xml file into a dataframe but can't figure out how to import each column seperatly because each tag is labeled cell.

```
<data>
    <row>
        <cell>pivotlink_gl</cell>
    </row>
    <row>
        <cell>Sent at: </cell>
        <cell>04/12/2023 01:18:00 PM MST</cell>
    </row>
    <row>
        <cell>Data Based on User: </cell>
        <cell>Report User</cell>
    </row>
    <row>
        <cell>Access Context Code: </cell>
        <cell>* (No Restrictions)</cell>
    </row>
    <row>
        <cell>Company</cell>
        <cell/>
        <cell>Set of Books</cell>
        <cell/>
        <cell>Partner Company</cell>
        <cell/>
        <cell>G/L Account</cell>
        <cell/>
        <cell>Journal Entry Type</cell>
        <cell>Journal Entry</cell>
        <cell>Journal Entry Header Text</cell>
        <cell>Journal Entry Item</cell>
        <cell>Journal Entry Item Text</cell>
        <cell>Cost Center</cell>
        <cell/>
        <cell>Source Doc. Type</cell>
        <cell>Source Doc. ID</cell>
        <cell>Posting Date</cell>
        <cell>Created On</cell>
        <cell>Creation Time (UTC)</cell>
        <cell>Transaction Currency</cell>
        <cell>Line Item Currency</cell>
        <cell>Company Currency</cell>
        <cell>Credits</cell>
        <cell>Debits</cell>
        <cell>Company Currency Amount</cell>
    </row>
    <row>
        <cell>100000</cell>
        <cell>Skullcandy, Inc</cell>
        <cell>GAAP</cell>
        <cell>GAAP</cell>
        <cell>600000</cell>
        <cell>Skullcandy Int GmbH</cell>
        <cell>500120</cell>
        <cell>Marketing &amp; Advertising - Digital and Social</cell>
        <cell>Supplier Credit Memo</cell>
        <cell>220000000089</cell>
        <cell>APRIL22 DIGITAL MEDIA CREDIT</cell>
        <cell>2</cell>
        <cell>APRIL22 DIGITAL MEDIA CREDIT</cell>
        <cell>131150</cell>
        <cell>Digital</cell>
        <cell>Supplier Invoice</cell>
        <cell>80039</cell>
        <cell>05/19/2022</cell>
        <cell>05/31/2022</cell>
        <cell>20:01:46</cell>
        <cell>USD</cell>
        <cell>USD</cell>
        <cell>USD</cell>
        <cell>-87252.64</cell>
        <cell/>
        <cell>-87252.64</cell>
    </row>
    <row>
        <cell>100000</cell>
        <cell>Skullcandy, Inc</cell>
        <cell>GAAP</cell>
        <cell>GAAP</cell>
        <cell>600000</cell>
        <cell>Skullcandy Int GmbH</cell>
        <cell>500120</cell>
        <cell>Marketing &amp; Advertising - Digital and Social</cell>
        <cell>Supplier Credit Memo</cell>
        <cell>220000000089</cell>
        <cell>APRIL22 DIGITAL MEDIA CREDIT</cell>
        <cell>3</cell>
        <cell>APRIL22 DIGITAL MEDIA CREDIT</cell>
        <cell>151030</cell>
        <cell>Marketing - Brand</cell>
        <cell>Supplier Invoice</cell>
        <cell>80039</cell>
        <cell>05/19/2022</cell>
        <cell>05/31/2022</cell>
        <cell>20:01:46</cell>
        <cell>USD</cell>
        <cell>USD</cell>
        <cell>USD</cell>
        <cell>-5.77</cell>
        <cell/>
        <cell>-5.77</cell>
    </row>
    <row>
        <cell>100000</cell>
        <cell>Skullcandy, Inc</cell>
        <cell>GAAP</cell>
        <cell>GAAP</cell>
        <cell>600000</cell>
        <cell>Skullcandy Int GmbH</cell>
        <cell>517999</cell>
        <cell>Other Costs for Reclass Entries</cell>
        <cell>Manual Posting - Journal Entry Voucher</cell>
        <cell>470000000105</cell>
        <cell>1 2023 ICO ROYALTY RCLS - U.10</cell>
        <cell>1</cell>
        <cell>GmbH ICO Royalty Rcls</cell>
        <cell>#</cell>
        <cell>Not assigned</cell>
        <cell>Journal Entry Voucher</cell>
        <cell>470000004310</cell>
        <cell>01/31/2023</cell>
        <cell>02/07/2023</cell>
        <cell>00:34:37</cell>
        <cell>USD</cell>
        <cell>USD</cell>
        <cell>USD</cell>
        <cell/>
        <cell>204468.43</cell>
        <cell>204468.43</cell>
    </row>
    <row>
        <cell>100000</cell>
        <cell>Skullcandy, Inc</cell>
        <cell>GAAP</cell>
        <cell>GAAP</cell>
        <cell>600000</cell>
        <cell>Skullcandy Int GmbH</cell>
        <cell>517999</cell>
        <cell>Other Costs for Reclass Entries</cell>
        <cell>Manual Posting - Journal Entry Voucher</cell>
        <cell>470000000234</cell>
        <cell>2 2023 ICO ROYALTY RCLS - U.10</cell>
        <cell>1</cell>
        <cell>GmbH ICO Royalty Rcls</cell>
        <cell>#</cell>
        <cell>Not assigned</cell>
        <cell>Journal Entry Voucher</cell>
        <cell>470000004364</cell>
        <cell>02/28/2023</cell>
        <cell>03/06/2023</cell>
        <cell>23:14:09</cell>
        <cell>USD</cell>
        <cell>USD</cell>
        <cell>USD</cell>
        <cell/>
        <cell>142674.51</cell>
        <cell>142674.51</cell>
    </row>
</data>
```

instead it inputs all the data into a single column which makes sense because each tag is labeled 'cell'. My column heads are all specified in the first row section.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's the rigtht format you expect but [elementtree](/questions/tagged/elementtree) seems a good start :

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import pandas as pd
​
tree = ET.parse("file.xml")
​
data = []
for row in tree.getroot().findall(".//row"):
    cells = [cell.text for cell in row.findall(".//cell")]
    data.append(cells)
​
df = pd.DataFrame(data[5:], columns=data[4])
```

​
Output :

```
print(df)

  Company             None  ...     Debits Company Currency Amount
0  100000  Skullcandy, Inc  ...       None               -87252.64
1  100000  Skullcandy, Inc  ...       None                   -5.77
2  100000  Skullcandy, Inc  ...  204468.43               204468.43
3  100000  Skullcandy, Inc  ...  142674.51               142674.51

[4 rows x 26 columns]
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the `names` argument of [**pandas.read_xml**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_xml.html)
where you can supply a list for same named nodes. Below includes *Unknown Columns* which show as empty in column row of XML.

```py
import pandas as pd

cols = [
    "Company", "Unknown_Column1",
    "Set of Books", "Unknown_Column2",
    "Partner Company", "Unknown_Column3",
    "G/L Account", "Unknown_Column4", 
    "Journal Entry Type", "Journal Entry", 
    "Journal Entry Header Text",
    "Journal Entry Item", "Journal Entry Item Text", 
    "Cost Center", "Unknown_Column5", 
    "Source Doc. Type", "Source Doc. ID",
    "Posting Date", "Created On", "Creation Time (UTC)",
    "Transaction Currency", "Line Item Currency", "Company Currency", 
    "Credits", "Debits", "Company Currency Amount"
]

cell_df = pd.read_xml(
    "Input.xml", xpath = ".//row[position()>5]", names = cols
)
```

Additionally, in using `read_xml`, you can take advantage of the other IO arguments such as `dtype` and `parse_dates`. Below converts all `object` types are convered as `string` and concatenates the date and time portion of creation date.

```py
str_cols = [
    "Unknown_Column1",
    "Set of Books", "Unknown_Column2",
    "Unknown_Column3", "Unknown_Column4", 
    "Journal Entry Type",
    "Journal Entry Header Text",
    "Journal Entry Item Text", 
    "Cost Center", "Unknown_Column5", 
    "Source Doc. Type",
    "Transaction Currency", "Line Item Currency", "Company Currency"
]

cell_df = pd.read_xml(
    "Input.xml", 
    xpath = ".//row[position()>5]",
    names = cols,
    dtype = {i: "string" for i in str_cols},
    parse_dates = [17, [18, 19]]
)
```

**Output**

```
print(cell_df)

  Created On_Creation Time (UTC)  Company  Unknown_Column1 Set of Books  ... Company Currency   Credits     Debits  Company Currency Amount
0            2022-05-31 20:01:46   100000  Skullcandy, Inc         GAAP  ...              USD -87252.64        NaN                -87252.64
1            2022-05-31 20:01:46   100000  Skullcandy, Inc         GAAP  ...              USD     -5.77        NaN                    -5.77
2            2023-02-07 00:34:37   100000  Skullcandy, Inc         GAAP  ...              USD       NaN  204468.43                204468.43
3            2023-03-06 23:14:09   100000  Skullcandy, Inc         GAAP  ...              USD       NaN  142674.51                142674.51
```

```
print(cell_df.info())

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 4 entries, 0 to 3
Data columns (total 25 columns):
 #   Column                          Non-Null Count  Dtype         
---  ------                          --------------  -----         
 0   Created On_Creation Time (UTC)  4 non-null      datetime64[ns]
 1   Company                         4 non-null      int64         
 2   Unknown_Column1                 4 non-null      string        
 3   Set of Books                    4 non-null      string        
 4   Unknown_Column2                 4 non-null      string        
 5   Partner Company                 4 non-null      int64         
 6   Unknown_Column3                 4 non-null      string        
 7   G/L Account                     4 non-null      int64         
 8   Unknown_Column4                 4 non-null      string        
 9   Journal Entry Type              4 non-null      string        
 10  Journal Entry                   4 non-null      int64         
 11  Journal Entry Header Text       4 non-null      string        
 12  Journal Entry Item              4 non-null      int64         
 13  Journal Entry Item Text         4 non-null      string        
 14  Cost Center                     4 non-null      string        
 15  Unknown_Column5                 4 non-null      string        
 16  Source Doc. Type                4 non-null      string        
 17  Source Doc. ID                  4 non-null      int64         
 18  Posting Date                    4 non-null      datetime64[ns]
 19  Transaction Currency            4 non-null      string        
 20  Line Item Currency              4 non-null      string        
 21  Company Currency                4 non-null      string        
 22  Credits                         2 non-null      float64       
 23  Debits                          2 non-null      float64       
 24  Company Currency Amount         4 non-null      float64       
dtypes: datetime64[ns](2), float64(3), int64(6), string(14)
```